# How to return corresponding parent expression of clang::DeclRefExpr object

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang++

I want to return corresponding parent `expr` of `DeclRefExpr`, for this `getExprStmt` seemed useful (`DeclRefExpr` inherits `getExprStmt` from `clang::ValueStmt`). But I cannot find any information regarding it in documentation or clang mailing list.

By corresponding parent expr of DeclRefExpr I meant, if, given `expr` object,and we obtain `DeclRefExpr` object as follows,

```
Expr* expr;  // have some valid value
DeclRefExpr* ref = nullptr;
if(auto ICE = dyn_cast<ImplicitCastExpr>(expr)) {
  ref = dyn_cast<DeclRefExpr>(ICE->getSubExpr());
}
```

Then in this example, `expr` is the corresponding parent expression of `ref`.

Can `clang::ValueStmt::getExprStmt()` help me for this ? I can't find any information regarding this function in documentation or clang mailing list

Please guide me how can I obtain `expr` from `ref`.